# How to get XML comments to appear in Visual Studio Class Wizard decriptions

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, intellisense, xml-comments

I have put XML comments in a C++ source file that IntelliSense appears to pick up and use.  It creates a project xml file, and IntelliSense works when I edit the original source file (showing me comments when I'm selecting a member function or entering parameters).

But, when I go to the Class Wizard in Visual Studio 2012 Express, the entered descriptions don't appear anywhere (on the methods, for example, down at the bottom of the dialog, where description remains sadly empty).  For that matter, IntelliSense only works in the original file(s), so when using a call in a separate file, none of my XML comments get picked up.  Why does it only work in the original source file?  What have I neglected to do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've neglected to do anything, unfortunately.

The Class Wizard was built *long* before Visual Studio supported XML doc comments, so it's more likely that no one remembered/cared to go back add support for them to the Class Wizard dialog.

In my experience, although it sounds like you've had slightly better luck, XML doc comments are not particularly well supported when using C++. For example, VS 2012 was the first version to support them in IntelliSense (and even that is incomplete). You get nothing in VS 2010 and earlier versions, despite the fact that they'll happily output a project XML file. That pathetic lack of support, combined with the angle bracket tax, drove me to switch to Doxygen when writing C++ code.

Comment: The Class Wizard was rewritten for Visual Studio 2010. It's not the Class Wizard from Visual Studio 6 anymore.